# Serve request by sending to loopback

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

We have a legacy server that receive requests in 2 ways:

1. Http REST requests via Jetty
2. Raw TCP sockets

We have a new requirement to process a raw request (delivered via TCP) and delegate this request to be processed by Jetty internally as if it would arrived via regular HTTP request.

Is that possible?

If not I guess the naive way would be to create an HTTP client and post it to ourselves as soon as we get data on the TCP socket.

Comment: One possible way is to forward the request as following:

`RequestDispatcher dispatcher = m_servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/forwarded");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);`

Comment: Is there a good way to create `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` instances without actually invoking http request?